# Select distinct values from an XML file via PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an XML file structured as follows:

```
<users>
 <user>
  <name>Fred</name>
 </user>
 <user>
  <name>Fred</name>
 </user>
 <user>
  <name>Bob</name>
 </user>
</users>
```

I am trying to use XPath to return a list of distinct names:

```
$page = simplexml_load_file('data/data.xml');

$dims = $page->xpath('/users/user[not(@name=preceding-sibling::user/@name)]/@name');
```

This does not appear to work. Any idea how to do this? Perhaps load to array and parse array?

Comment: thanks - typos fixed :)

Comment: There should never be any "typos". You should copy/paste any relevant content whenever possible. Is this now the _actual_ XML that you're working with?

Comment: Yes. This is the actual XML I am working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@name` is attribute syntax, you want to use `name` to consider element names:

```
$dims = $page->xpath('/users/user[not(name=preceding-sibling::user/name)]/name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to use an array is correct. Simply create a new array to hold the uniques, iterate through the list of users, and if the current user isn't already in the array, add it.

```
$page = simplexml_load_file('data/data.xml');

$uniqueUsers = array();

foreach($obj as $userObj)
{
    if(!in_array((string)$page->name, $uniqueUsers))
    {
        $uniqueUsers[] = (string)$page->name;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/5XA5L)

Answer (score -3):

Yeah an array would be much easier to parse:

```
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```